# unable to apply css inside shadow root ionic 5

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I created tab application and need to expand active tab but I'm not able to apply CSS under the shadow element like below.[refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvEDg.png)

I want to give

```
Overflow : "visible"   to .button-native inside shahow root
```

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5ggU.png) result.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got my respective example  the beautiful tabs in ionic 5

https://github.com/rajneshbiz/ionic-custom-components/tree/master/ionic-v4-v5/tabs-custom-icon-floating-button

Answer (score 0):

I created a recursive method and I called in the AfterViewInit hook..

```
setStyle() {
    const all = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-has-icon');

    if(all.length === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setStyle();
      }, 0);
      return;
    }

    all.forEach(el => {
      el.shadowRoot.querySelector('.button-native').setAttribute('style','overflow: inherit')
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find 2 metods in SASS: you cant use pseudoelement ::part, this you can find in your button shadow

```
<button type="button" class="button-native" part="native"><span class="button-inner"><slot name="icon-only"></slot><slot name="start"></slot><slot></slot><slot name="end"></slot></span><ion-ripple-effect role="presentation" class="md hydrated"></ion-ripple-effect></button>
```

you can see part ion-button is "native" so your css can be:

```
  ion-button::part(native){
overflow: visible!important;}
```

and in javascript you can access to shadown element like:

```
 document.querySelector("ion-button")
    .shadowRoot
    .querySelector(".button-native").setAttribute("style","overflow:visible")
```